# searching an unordered integer array

Tags: java, arrays, search

what is the best way to search the index and the value of an integer element belonging to a big unordered integer array? which is the best searching tecnhique/algorithm for this process?

```
int[] temp = new int[]{1,4,3,6,7,8,5,2,9,......}
```

now say, i would like to search for the element '9' and i need to get its index of that element as well. what i mean to say is, sorting the array elements and determining it wouldnt work here(since i need to keep track of the index of the element as well). any suggestions? i am working on java by the way..

Comment: I don't think you have a choice, since you want to keep the index. Search iteratively.

Comment: can i use hashing and store the index of the element as the value?

Comment: Would it prohibitive to sort the elements as you were constructing the collection?

Comment: depends on what you are trying to achieve/solve. probably array is not a best data structure in your task.

Comment: How large is the array? Does it ever change? How frequently do you need to search?

Comment: i need to search an array of size 10,000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to search (the same array) multiple times, you might create a temporary structure, which combines the original index and the value:

```
class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
    final int index;
    final int value;

    Pair(int index, int value) {
        this.index = index;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int compareTo(Pair oth) {
        if (value < oth.value) return -1;
        else if (value > oth.value) return 1;
        else if (index < oth.index) return -1;
        else if (index > oth.index) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
}

final ArrayList<Pair> list = new ArrayList<Pair>();

for (int k = 0; k < array.length; ++k) {
    list.add(new Pair(k, array[k]);
}

Arrays.sort(list);
```

Now, `list` is sorted by value and then by index. We can now use binary search (for example) to look elements up. Note, though, that this is only worthwhile, if the number of times, you search for a value (now `O(log n)` as opposed to `O(n)`), dominates the time it takes to build the array (`(O(n log n)` due to sorting).

Alternatively, you could build an index-like structure using `HashMap` or `TreeMap`, which maps from integer value to its position in the array. In the case of using `HashMap`, the access time would be around `O(1)`, in the case of the `TreeMap` it would be `O(log n)`, as with the binary-search approach proposed above.

All these suggestions are clearly worthwhile only, if you have to search the array often.

Also, you should consider, that if the array is reasonably small, using a plain linear search (as suggested by others) might actually be the fastest solution due to the low "constants" involved and the good locality of the array components.

So, yet another approach could be to unpack the `Pair` structure again after sorting into two integer arrays (one containing the values, the other containing the indices):

```
int[] values = new int[list.size()];
int[] indices = new int[list.size()];
int pt = 0;

for (Pair p: list) {
    values[pt] = p.value;
    indices[pt] = p.index;
    pt += 1;
}
```

Now you can search the `values` array using binary search:

```
int position = Arrays.binarySearch(values, valueToLookFor);
if (position >= 0) {

    // Found it!
    int index = indices[position];

    System.out.println("Value was originally stored in " + index);

} else {

    // Value not found
}
```

Please keep in mind: the simplest solution (linear scan) might be the fastest, depending on the size of the array and the number of times you need to search for an entry. I would actually try that first, and only use one of the more complex proposals, if it turns out to be a bottle neck.

Comment: thanks for the comprehensive solution, i used a hashmap to solve my problem finally!!

Answer (score 6):

If you were doing it manually you could just iterate over each array item:

```
public int indexOf(int search, int[] arr) {

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == search) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;

}
```

If you know the array wont change in between doing many searches, you can cache the results too, using a Map.. just empty the cache whenever you change the array.

```
private Map<Integer, Integer> indexCache;

public int indexOf(int search, int[] arr) {

    Integer cachedIndex = indexCache.get(search);
    if(cachedIndex != null) return cachedIndex;

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] == search) {
            indexCache.put(search, i);
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;

}
```

In reality you may be better off using a Map instead of an array altogether to store this data as it is better suited to key value lookup.

Comment: By conversion in Java, it's better to put param `int[] arr` before `int search` in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced For :

```
  int[] temp = new int[]{1,4,3,6,7,8,5,2,9,......}
    for (int i : temp) {
      if (i == 9)
        // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Begin at the beginning and go on till you come to the end: then stop.](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/34976.html)

**Lewis Carroll**

Unless of course you find what you are looking for before you get to the end.

Answer (score -1):

Least coding would be:

```
Arrays.asList(temp).indexOf(9)
```

Comment: This would sweep over the list twice I believe. Just using an enhanced for loop would be the best way to do this.

Comment: is this solution similar to linear searching process?

Comment: it would sweep over the list twice? i guess then linear searching using a for loop would be better. yes.

Comment: @Eashwar Cowls' answer is the best. If you look at the source for this code you will see it iterates over the list twice, being half as efficient.

Comment: @Legend, why are talking about efficiency? The OP does not specify any of his requirements.

Comment: thanks for the solution guys, i guess i'll go with the enhanced for approach!

Comment: It is best to practice effeciency when ever you an, so it is not a struggle when you need it.

Comment: @Legend I know that this approach is not most efficient, but if lookup is needed once in 10-line program, there is no need to implement own method.

Comment: Since Louis Wasserman pointed out your solution does not work for the int[] specified in the question, why not delete your answer? It may confuse other readers.

Answer (score -1):

Better approach is to sort the array first.

```
Arrays.sort(array);
Arrays.binarySearch(array, value);
```

To scan through an unsorted array takes linear time "O(n)". You can try this if you don't want to sort the array:

```
public int find(int[] array, int value) {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i] == value) { index = i; }
        }
        return index;            
    }
```

Comment: this is a comment, not answer.